# PHP robust include to handle errors?

Tags: php, exception, include

I have a PHP app "index.php" that, for various reasons, needs to run other PHP scripts by using `include_once` on that other script.  That other script isn't very stable, so is there some way to do a safe `include_once` that won't halt the caller?

i.e.:

```
<?php

safely_include_once('badfile.php'); // MAY throw syntax error, parse error, other badness
echo "I can continue execution after error";

?>
```

(I know what a bad idea this can be, etc., rest assured this isn't production-environment stuff.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just

```
@include "fileWithBadSyntax.php";
```

Which, from my quick tests, works for both parse errors or errors thrown with trigger_error().

**EDIT**: This is completely wrong.  See sneak's answer, which is correct, if somewhat unhelpful.

Comment: Does the job, would it be possible to capture the error details with this approach?

Comment: This approach will silence all errors. See KyleFarris' answer for a method that will catch errors and can optionally keep them quiet (IE, custom error handling).

Comment: Indeed, Kyle's answer is more powerful

Comment: Someone just upvoted this, and I can't believe I wrote it.  If it wasn't the accepted answer, I would delete it.

Answer (score 36):

None of these answers will work.  The top-voted one, which says to @include(), will still terminate the first script if there is a parse error in the included file.

You can't eval() it, you can't try/catch it, and every way of calling include or require will terminate *all* execution in the script.

This question remains OPEN and UNSOLVED.

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41810

This is a bug in PHP, and this functionality's been missing since at least 2006.  They classified the bug as "bogus" because, they claim, includes() and requires() happen at compile-time.

This goes out the window if you are generating the string arguments to include() and/or require() at RUNTIME, or doing an eval() over a string containing code that runs an include().

Comment: There has to be a way, Wordpress is able to do this. If you activate a plugin which has a syntax error or generates a warning / fatal error, it tells you that and continues the script (disabling the plugin, and showing the error message). eg: "Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error." I believe it does this through iframe trickery, though, which is not ideal. But I am not sure.

Comment: Graben's answer, using the interpreter command line with the `-f` flag, will work. It is slow, and seems like a hack, but it does get the job done.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41810#1349470363 is a comment worth reading on the mentioned bug report.

Answer (score 10):

The only real solution, thought not the most elegant one but works is to call in another php interpretor that parses and execute the script for nothing else than checking if it yields a parse error or a No errors detected message to filter error messages like PHP Parse Error blablabla. like this code does :

```
<?php
function ChkInc($file){
   return file_exists($file) && (substr(exec("php -l $file"), 0, 28) == "No syntax errors detected in");
}
?>
```

This idea came from [*gillis*' comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#51896) to `include` function manual page at PHP doc.

Comment: This is the only way to do this, currently.

Comment: Using `if` to return true or false? Doesn't this sound like a madness? What is wrong about converting your solution into one-liner: `return (substr(exec("php -l $file"), 0, 28) == "No syntax errors detected in");`?

Comment: ChkInc("/tmp ; rm -rf /");

Comment: Added the file_exists check for sneak comment, but user input validation should have been done already when reaching this function in a decent application.

Answer (score 2):

Would it be possible to change your architecture and turn "badfile.php" into a web service?  Instead of including it directly into your codebase, you would call it over the network and parse or include its output.  This will get you around parse errors, you could also avoid potentially malicious code if you have badfile.php's environment limited appropriately (using safe_mode, or running a separate web server process with limited privileges).

Comment: @pix0r: This would certainly work but depending on the scope of his project it might just be a bit overkill and inelegant.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a try/catch block

```
<?php
try {
    include("someFile.php");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Should probably write it to a log file, but... for brevity's sake:
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

Now, it will only include the file if there is no error. If there is an error, it will just skip this stuff and write the exception (like, in the comments, preferably to a log file or something).

For more info:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: A parse error will stop PHP in the middle of the included file and it won't return to the `catch` block.

Answer (score 2):

Graceful workaround for include-file-not-found ....

```
function safe_require( $incfile, $showfn=1 ) {
  $a = explode( ":", get_include_path() ) ;
  $a[] = "";
  $b = 0;
  foreach( $a as $p ) {
    if( !empty( $p )) $p .= "/";
    $f = $p.$incfile;
    if( file_exists( $f )) {
      $b = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if( !$b ) 
    exit( "Cannot proceed, required file " . 
          (($showfn) ? $incfile : "" ) . " is unavailable or server has timed out." 
        );
  require_once( "$f" );
}
```

Comment: Pretty good, but still failable. Imagine the file is deleted after you've verified it to exist....

Answer (score 0):

See the second answer, @sneak is right, you cant catch requires / includes.

My solution for autoload require was to use error_get_last, so just add this in the base file (this will then handle parse errors from requires/include included by things such as auto-load / child classes:

```
<?php 
    register_shutdown_function( "fatal_handler" );
    function fatal_handler() 
    {
        $error = error_get_last();  
        if($error !== NULL) 
        {
            if(isset($error['type']) && ($error['type'] === E_ERROR  || $error['type'] === 1 || $error['type'] === 2 || $error['type'] === 3 || $error['type'] === 4))
            {
                // do what you need to do here to make safe, I just log and use that log (to make sure other tests dont run in my case)
                Some_Class::logErrorToFile('fatal_error:' . json_encode($error));
                file_put_contents('somp_file_path_that_all_other_classes_check', 'fatal_error:' . json_encode($error));
            }
            else
            {
                Some_Class::logErrorToFile('error:' . json_encode($error)); 
            }
        }
        return;
    }

spl_autoload_register(function ($classname) {
    $classPath = str_replace("_", "/", $classname);
    $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'.$classPath.'.php';
    require_once($path);  // fatal errors are logged for this runtime require, will not actually stop execution for this case, but we can handle how we deal with that now      
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In badfile.php you could make it return a value:

```
<?php
//inestable instructions.


return true; ?>
```

then on main file you could do:

```
 <?php

 if (require($badFile)) {
     //if it was true continue with normal execution
 } else {
     echo "Error: ". error_get_last();
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

Here's the only real solution I've been able to find:

```
function safe_include($fn) {
        $fc = file_get_contents($fn);
        if(!eval($fc)) {
                return 0;
        }
        return 1;
}
```

Note that the above code means you have to take out the opening  statements from your to-be-included files, or do the following:

```
eval("?>" . $fc)
```

The problem is that you can't call require() or include() or their _once() variants at any point and expect them not to terminate *everything*, including any error handlers.  PHP will completely stop processing everything when it encounters a parse error.

The only exception to this is the string inside of an eval().  The problem is, though, that you can't really do this:

```
eval('require($fn);');
```

...because the require() inside the eval'd string will *still* stop.  You have to read in the contents, pray that the file in question doesn't include() or require() further, and eval() it.

The real solution?  Skip PHP. :/